# ScrollViewer has line across at topmost and bottommost positions

Tags: c#, xaml, scrollviewer, wrappanel

I have a ScrollViewer, which contains a set of items in a WrapPanel.  The xaml tree is as follows:

```
<Grid>
  <ScrollViewer>
     <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding xyz}" Tag="{Binding .}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <Grid>
              <Button.... styling etc.>
```

When scrolled to the very top or very bottom position, a white line appears across the control- image is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO8Mt.jpg

This is happening in a view which uses VisualStates.  There are other visual states which use a ScrollViewer, and this problem does NOT happen.  The only thing unique about this particular visual state is the use of the ItemsPanel/WrapPanel.  I've tried removing this just to isolate the cause of the problem, and even when I take it our the issue persists.

Seems almost like the scroller fails to fully refresh/paint when it gets to the first/last index.

Has anyone seen something like this before?

Interestingly enough, if I run my application in debug, the scroller displays perfectly fine.  Only when launching a release build does the problem present itself.